# Javascript no reconoce "Ciertas cadenas"?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo un botón (MODIFICAR) que al pulsar pone en un input type=text el valor de input de un formulario.

Lo hace **bien con** números **normales**,pero no con numeros 1B:3B:3B:4B:5B:6B o con 1C-3C-3C-4C-5B-6B 

Ni siquiera entra a la función javascript para decir alert("hola");
pero si son números "80" - "5" lo hace bien.

```
@foreach($datos_usuario as $value) 
            <tr>
            <form action="Borrar_mac" id="idformac_usu" name="formac_usu" method="POST" >
                {!! csrf_field(); !!}
                <td><input type="text" name="txtdireccion_mac" readonly="readonly" value="{!! $value->Direccion_mac !!}" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_descripcion" readonly="readonly" value="{!! $value->Descripcion !!}"  readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtfecha" readonly="readonly" value=" {!! $value->Fecha !!} "  readonly></td>

           AQUÍ--->     <td><input type="button" name="modificar" onclick="cambiarMac({!! $value -> Direccion_mac !!})" value="Modificar Mac" ></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="btn_borrar" value="Borrar Mac"></td>

            </form>
        </tr>   
        @endforeach   
  </table>

   <!--    Modificar    -->     

    <div id='formulario_cambio_mac'>
        <form action='cambiar_datos_mac' id="idform_cambiar" method='POST'>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
 function cambiarMac(mac){
                alert("entro");
                var txt1 = '{!! csrf_field(); !!}';
                txt1 += "<input type='hidden' name='identificador_mac' id='id_identificadormac' value=''>";
                txt1 += "<label for='nueva_mac'>Modifica la Mac <input type='text' name='nuevatxtmac' id='id_cambiar_mac' value='' onblur='comprobar_formato_mac(this,mod);' required></label><br/>";
                txt1 += "<label for='nueva_descripcion'>Escribe la Descripcion  <input type='text' name='txtdescripcion' id='iddescripcion' value='' required></label><br/>";
                txt1 += "<input type='submit' name='btn_enviar' value='Cambiar Mac'>";
                txt1 += "<input type='button' name='btn_no_hacer' onclick='No_realizar();' value='No realizar'>";

                document.getElementById("idform_cambiar").innerHTML = txt1;
                document.getElementById('id_identificadormac').value = mac;
                document.getElementById('id_cambiar_mac').value = mac;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema es al pasar los valores desde php en:

```
onclick="cambiarMac({!! $value -> Direccion_mac !!})"
```

si pasas un valor numérico como por ejemplo `48` quedaría como:

```
onclick="cambiarMac(48)"
```

quedando una instrucción javascript válida que llama a la función `cambiarMac` con un argumento numérico `48`.

Pero si pasas un valor como el que comentas por ejemplo `1B:3B:3B:4B:5B:6B`, quedaría:

```
onclick="cambiarMac(1B:3B:3B:4B:5B:6B)"
```

lo que javascript no va a reconocer como un valor válido. Si el valor no va a ser siempre numérico deberías pasarlo como una cadena (añadiéndole comillas):

```
onclick="cambiarMac('{!! $value -> Direccion_mac !!}')"
```

de esta forma quedaría como

```
onclick="cambiarMac('1B:3B:3B:4B:5B:6B')"
```

lo que sí se interpretará como un valor válido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si muestra el valor en el input, pero sigo teniendo problemas. Al cambiar esa expresión, tengo un onblur para comprobar que se está llevando bien el formato, y no está pasando por javascript del onblur Tengo que crear un nuevo tema ?

Comment: Sí, mejor crea una nueva pregunta porque a primera vista no parece que el problema tenga relación

Comment: txt1 += "<label for='nueva_mac'>Modifica la Mac <input type='text' name='nuevatxtmac' id='id_cambiar_mac' value='' onblur='comprobar_formato_mac(this,mod);' required></label><br/>";
Esa linea no esta llamando al comprobar_formato_mac

Comment: Cuando me has ayudado a pasarlo al input, ese input tiene un onblur para que si cambias, siga teniendo el mismo formato, pero ese input no está llamando al javascrit

Comment: Es complicado. Habría que ver el código html generado por el php y el javascript completo. Así, a primera vista, no veo porqué puede ser; aunque sí me pega al ojo esa variable `mod` que se le pasa que no sé de dónde sale.

Comment: gracias, era por el mod, no lo reconoce bien el javascript =)